# React Native Handling fetch Errors to externel File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

### **I want to catch errors and trait it in Errors.js**

*1: I catched the errors but can't read the status of error :(*

```
export function getBestFilmsFromApi (page) {
  return fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=' + API_TOKEN + '&vote_count.gte=1000&sort_by=release_date.desc&language=fr&page=' + page)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error.response.status)

      this.props.navigation.navigate('Errors',{ error }) **I want to send this Error to file Errors.js and to trait it **
    });
}
```

---

**Errors.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View,Platform,Animated, Easing,Dimensions,PanResponder,Alert } from 'react-native'

class Errors extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      topPostition:0,
      leftPosition:0,
      valeur: this.props.navigation.state.params.error

    }

    }


    _Errors(){


switch (this.state.valeur.error) {
    case 201:
     Alert.alert('Requête traitée avec succès')
      break
      case 404:
      Alert.alert("Ressource non trouvée")
            break
      case 405:
      Alert.alert('Méthode de requête non autorisée')
      break
      case 406:
      Alert.alert('La ressource demandée ne pas disponible')
      break
      case 408:
      Alert.alert('Temps attente d’une requête du client, écoulé côté serveur')
      break
      case 409:
      Alert.alert('La requête ne peut être traitée en l’état actuel.')
      break
      case 421:
      Alert.alert('La requête a été envoyée à un serveur qui ne pas capable de produire une réponse')
      break
      case 444:
      Alert.alert('serveur na retourné aucune information')
      break
      case 498:
      Alert.alert('Le jeton a expiré ou est invalide')
      break
      case 499:
      Alert.alert('Client Closed Request')
      break

    case 511:
    alert("besoin de connexion");
     break
    default:
    Alert.alert('unhandled')
      break
  }

    }


  render() {
    return (
      {_Errors}
    )
  }

}

export default Errors
```

---

What are you trying to achieve what are you expecting to get out What did you get out (include error messages) What else have you tried? What do you think is causing it? Why do you need to make a new question for it? Why is your problem different to other, similar questions on here?